# Foreach is not checking properly in mvc when doing a workflow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Am doing a workflow cheching in which i have 2 values and the when the foreach condition is checked only one time it enters the loop and exits out without going to the next one.

```
  public CustomBusinessServices InvokeWorkFlowPermissionBusinessRule(dynamic workFlowImplemented, out string serviceName, out int permissionId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<WorkflowEligibilityMapping> workFlowPermissionService = new List<WorkflowEligibilityMapping>();// to handle null values
            int current_ControllerId = Convert.ToInt32(workFlowImplemented); //ControllerId
            using (var db = new AdminDb())
            {
                //to select services against this controller
                workFlowPermissionService = (from definition in db.WorkFlowDefinition.AsNoTracking()
                                             join model in db.WorkFlowModel.AsNoTracking()
                                             on definition.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals model.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                                             join permission in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                                             on model.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals permission.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                                             where model.ControllerNameId.Equals(current_ControllerId)
                                             select new WorkflowEligibilityMapping
                                             {
                                                 Service = permission.Service,
                                                 WorkFlowPermissionId = permission.WorkFlowPermissionId
                                             }).ToList();
            }

            int[] workFlowServiceDetails = workFlowPermissionService.Select(x => x.WorkFlowPermissionId).ToArray();

            //to Login userId
            var userId = Assyst.PanERP.Common.AppSession.Common.UserID;

            /*******************Issue in foreach i think**************************************/
            foreach (int workFlowServiceDetail in workFlowServiceDetails)

            /*******workFlowServiceDetails have 2 valus********/
            {
                using (var db = new AdminDb())
                {
                    string workFlowServiceDtl = (from perm in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                                                 where perm.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                                                 select perm.Service).FirstOrDefault();

                    //to select eligibility rules against this service
                    string eligibility = (from definition in db.WorkFlowDefinition.AsNoTracking()
                                          join model in db.WorkFlowModel.AsNoTracking()
                                          on definition.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals model.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                                          join permission in db.WorkFlowPermission.AsNoTracking()
                                          on model.WorkFlowDefinitionId equals permission.WorkFlowDefinitionId
                                          where model.ControllerNameId.Equals(current_ControllerId) && permission.WorkFlowPermissionId == workFlowServiceDetail
                                          select permission.EligibilityRule).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (eligibility == null)
                    {
                        string validationMessage = "";
                        validationMessage = "Please set eligibility for workflow permission";
                        serviceName = null;
                        permissionId = 0;
                        return new CustomBusinessServices() { strMessage = validationMessage };
                    }

                    string[] strTxt = workFlowServiceDtl.Split(';'); //split the service name by ';' and strore it in an array
                    string serviceUrl = string.Empty;
                    string workFlowServiceName = string.Empty;
                    string classpath = string.Empty;
                    workFlowServiceName = strTxt[0].ToString();
                    workFlowServiceName = workFlowServiceName.Replace(" ", "");//get the service name by removing empty blank space for the word
                    classpath = strTxt[1].ToString();

                    //Invoke REST based service (like Node.Js service)
                    if (strTxt.Length == 4)
                    {
                        serviceUrl = strTxt[3].ToString();
                    }

                    //Invoke c# based service
                    else
                    {
                        serviceUrl = string.Empty;
                    }

                    var userLists = PermissionCallMethod(classpath, workFlowServiceName, new[] { workFlowImplemented, eligibility }, serviceUrl);

                    if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))
                    {
                        serviceName = strTxt[0].ToString() + ";Assyst.PanERP.Common.WorkFlowNotificationServices;" + strTxt[2].ToString();
                        permissionId = workFlowServiceDetail;
                        return userLists;
                    }
                }
            }
            serviceName = string.Empty;
            permissionId = 0;
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

workFlowServiceDetails have 2 values and the workFlowServiceDetail takes the first one and checks for it.goes through the loop and mapes the role for the first one to the user list at the end and the without checking the for the second vale it moves out of the loop. Please help me to make the loop work for 2 values.Is it some problem in the return part...?

Comment: could be because of array you are using, array starts from 0

just a wild guess

Comment: so how can i make it work then..? am new to this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (eligibility == null)
{
     string validationMessage = "";
     validationMessage = "Please set eligibility for workflow permission";
     serviceName = null;
     permissionId = 0;
     return new CustomBusinessServices() { strMessage = validationMessage };
}

if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))
{
     serviceName = strTxt[0].ToString() + ";Assyst.PanERP.Common.WorkFlowNotificationServices;" + strTxt[2].ToString();
     permissionId = workFlowServiceDetail;
     return userLists;
}
```

If any of the above if statements evaluates to true, your loop will exit without looping through the second item in your array.  The reason for this is that you are in your first conditional check do the following:

```
return new CustomBusinessServices() { strMessage = validationMessage };
```

And in your second:

```
return userLists;
```

The return statement will exit your method, and therefore terminate the foreach as well.

Try building your object first, and after your loop has walked through each item, do a return statement returning your object.

Comment: if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))..... this condition return true bcz while checking the user, it returns true..so can u say where i need to change it..

Comment: I am not exactly sure on what you are trying to do there, but your if statement is saying that if the userList contains the userID, you should only set the variables that you want, like the serviceName and permissionID, do not return anything in there.  Do not return your userLis

Comment: You are very correct...am checking the userId in that list and once its found its returing it. then where should i return that value..?

Comment: Assuming the point of the "return userList" is to return a list with valid User ID's, I would suggest you add that the userId to a List and after the closing bracket of the foreach loop, you can return your list.  But your method is not making sense, you set the serviceName and permissionId, but directly after the "if (userLists.UserList.Contains(userId))" you assign them blank values.

Comment: Only one userid is am getting from a that list. Actually this is not my code i was given this code and asked to modify..How can i add that to list...? regarding that serviceName and permissionId its not blank values i guess the workFlowServiceDetail is having one value. that is being asined to it.

Comment: You are going beyond the scope of your question. If this post answered your original question, please accept as solution.  If you need help on assigning values to lists in C#, I suggest you either google, there is a lot of questions on this, or ask a new question, just make sure there are not already questions related to your question.